# How can I correct this ESM error with Phusion Passenger?

Tags: javascript, node.js, node-modules, passenger

I'm trying to launch my NodeJS API on a production server using Phusion Passenger.
I used the last ECM syntax to import/export my modules.
However when trying to reach my api, Passenger returns this error message :

```
Error [ERR_REQUIRE_ESM]: Must use import to load ES Module: /home/***/api/server.mjs
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:948:11)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:790:14)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:974:19)
    at Module.require (/opt/passenger/src/helper-scripts/node-loader.js:80:25)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:92:18)
    at loadApplication (/opt/passenger/src/helper-scripts/node-loader.js:243:2)
    at setupEnvironment (/opt/passenger/src/helper-scripts/node-loader.js:214:2)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/opt/passenger/src/helper-scripts/node-loader.js:133:1)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1085:14)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1114:10) {
  code: 'ERR_REQUIRE_ESM'
```

I have the `"type": "module"` line in  my package.json and I tried to change the extension from .js to .mjs without effect.

I noticed that passenger uses CJS with "require" syntax to load my server.js as we can see here: https://github.com/phusion/passenger/blob/stable-6.0/src/helper-scripts/node-loader.js.

```
function loadApplication() {
    var appRoot = PhusionPassenger.options.app_root || process.cwd();
    var startupFile = PhusionPassenger.options.startup_file || (appRoot + '/' + 'app.js');
    require(startupFile);
}
```

So my **question** is: Is there any way not to change all my code from ECM to CJS to match with Passenger?

Answer (score 14):

An update to the code above - this would not work for me unless the dynamic import is called asynchronously:

Create an entry.cjs file and use an async/await to dynamically import your applications entry file that you would normally set in plesk:

```
// entry.cjs
async function loadApp() {
    const { app } = await import("./app.js"); // this is your normal entry file - (index.js, main.js, app.mjs etc.)
}
loadApp()
```

Then in Plesk set your application entry file to ./entry.cjs

Answer (score 8):

There's a way: Considering all your files have `.mjs` extension, you just need to create a `.js` to be the entry file for Passenger, and in this file (which is in CommonJS format) you can dynamically import the ESM one.

So, instead of running `node server.mjs` through Passenger, create a `entry.js` with the following content:

```js
import("./server.mjs");
```

And then call `node entry.js` through Passenger.

Note: you can use any other name for the `entry.js` file.

Answer (score 0):

Just in case you are working with typescript (that's my case), I managed to get rid of this error by compiling my code to commonJs module in **two simple steps**

1. change `"type": "module"` in your `packeage.json` file to `"type": "commonjs"`
2. change your `tsconfig.json` module to `"module": "CommonJS"`

Rebuild and now it should work :)